# Font size of a variable in Form

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i change font size of a variable in Html?

```
<form name=pad>
..
<script>
function rndize() {
    alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO ";
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
       x = 0;
       y = 0;
       while (document.pad.elements[4 * y + x].value != " ") {
          x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
          y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
       }
       document.pad.elements[4 * y + x].value = alpha.substring(i, i + 1);
    }
    bx = x;
    by = y;
}
rndize();
</script>
..
</form>
```

How can i change the font Size of the alphabet? Now it is Coming like normal ABCD only. How to change the size of variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write
document.pad.elements[4 * y + x].style.fontSize='12px';
Or similar.

Comment: It is not working. .style option is not coming for document.pad.elements[4 * y + x].

Comment: element[x].style property exists. i chnaged font-size to fontSize which is correct. Pls see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqb81wtj/

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery after document load, `$('elements').css('font-size','value')`, something like this

Comment: Is it not possible to do it inside this HTML form?

Comment: well you can try with <font size="3" color="red">your text</font> attribute but i am not sure if this will work for you

Comment: That is different thing.